# Are prepositions with "ke" valid? ("pri ke", "pro ke", "por ke", ...)

Tags: prepositions

To introduce a causal secondary sentence, I often saw *pro tio, ke* and *ĉar*.

Recently, I saw *pro ke*, without any *tio* to which I think *ke* is supposed to refer to.

> Mi ne povas dormi *pro ke* tro malvarmas kaj la hundo bojadas

This surprised me because it is uncommon. However, "por ke" is common, so if "por ke" is valid, is there any reason for "pro ke" to not be valid?

Answer (score 7):

This is a great question. It deserves a great answer. This is the best I can come up with on short notice.

You're absolutely right that *por ke* is common and *pro ke* is basically unheard of. My advice: **do not use *pro ke*.**

Why is this? My first thought was "tradition" (i.e. "just cos"), but that's not always a good answer. My second thought was that traditionally we give more flexibility to *por* to interact with more parts of speech than we do for most other prepositions. (*Por* is frequently used with infinitives, for example, while most other prepositions stick to nouns.)

My impression, though, is that there is a good semantical reason for saying *por ke* and avoiding *pro ke*. Consider the alternatives:

- pro tio ke (common)
- por tio ke (not common)

The meaning of *por ke* and *por tio ke* are different.

- por ke = in order that, for the purpose of
- por tio ke = for the following reason

As illustrated by the following sample sentences.

- Utilis **por tio ke** multaj ministroj de la nuna registaro estas dungitoj de okcidentaj entreprenoj aktivaj en Kongo.
- Faru ion al la homoj, **por ke** ili nenion al vi faru

The sentence you list with *pro ke* seems awkward to me and would read better with *pro tio ke*.

Comment: Your advice is to "not use *por ke*". Then how would you rearrange/restate your second example sentence (*Faru ion al la homoj, **por ke** ili nenion al vi faru*), to keep the same meaning?

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I meant **do not use *pro ke*.** I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 6):

These *tio*-less constructions are criticized in PMEG ([§33.2.3](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/ke/komplemento.html)) but no objection is given other than the fact that they are not traditional:

> Nur *por ke, malgraŭ ke, anstataŭ ke, krom ke* kaj *sen ke* estas ĝenerale akceptitaj. Sed nur malkutimeco estas argumento kontraŭ frazoj kiel: *Ni parolis, **pri ke** la prezoj ĉiam altiĝas. Oni argumentis, **kontraŭ ke** ili ekloĝu en la urbo. Li sukcesis eskapi, **pro ke** vi dormis. Tio okazis, **antaŭ ke** mi naskiĝis.* Malkutimeco estas tamen forta argumento. Oni ne senbezone esprimu sin en maniero tiel nekutima, ke oni eble ne estas komprenata.

In PAG (§124, §267) the authors say merely that *per ke, pri ke* are "ne uzataj" and that *pro ke* is "nekutima ĝis nun."

It is likely that some readers will see these expressions as "bad style"; however (speaking for myself) the cited sentences seem clear as day to me, and there are no good grounds for calling them ungrammatical.

- Zamenhof was quite happy with *por ke, malgraŭ ke,* etc, and the absence of *pro ke* in early texts is easy to understand given the neat alternatives: *ĉar; tial ke*.
- Not accepting them effectively introduces an irregularity into Esperanto, and a new unnecessary rule.
- The insertion of *tio* can be slightly confusing, as the reader or hearer naturally assumes that *tio* refers to something already mentioned, and instead must do a mental double-take: *Je la kvara horo la pluvo komenciĝis, kaj mi revenis pro tio, ke mi ege malsatis.* Or: *Mia amiko alvenis malfrue, kaj kiam li sidiĝis, mi longe parolis pri tio, ke nia enspezo senĉese malkreskas.* In English we have to insert *the fact that* or *the idea that* or resort to cumbersome periphrases: *pri la fakto ke*...